# is unmodifiableList thread safe?

Tags: java, unmodifiable

i have a list of string(tagList) which need to shared among multiple threads for reading, so i create a unmodifiable version of it and pass it to threads, i m not sure if it's thread safe, since threads only read that list so i guess it should be ok?

also when i pass that unmodifialble list to the threads, does it pass a single copy and shared by threads or does it create multiple copy and pass one copy to each thread?

here is my code:

```
final List<String> tList = Collections.unmodifiableList(tagList);
List<Future<Void>> calls = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();

FileStatus[] fsta = _fileSystem.listStatus(p);      
for (FileStatus sta : fsta) {
    final Path path = new Path(sta.getPath(), "data.txt");
    if (!_fileSystem.exists(path)) {        
        continue;
    }
    else {
        calls.add(_exec.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                filterData(path, tList);
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This completely depends on whether underlying list is thread safe on read operations.  Unmodifiable list just passes all read calls, such as `size ()`, `get (int)` etc to underlying list without additional synchronization.

Imagine, for example, implementation of List which caches hash code instead of calculating it each time it is needed.  For such implementation, `hashCode ()` method is actually not read-only, because it may modify internally cached hash code value.

Another example is a flavor of LinkedList which caches reference to last accessed entry together with its index, so further attempts to access nearby elements will be performed much faster.  For such implementation, method `get (int)` will be not read-only because it updates cached reference and index, and thus will probably be not thread safe.

Comment: And the underlying `List` may get modified. Also presumably unsafe if published unsafely.

Comment: The fact that underlying list may get modified has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: I don't follow. If the underlying `List` is being modified in a different thread than the `unmodifiedList` is being read, that's going to be multithreaded access even if read operation on the underlying `List` do not cause any internal modification.

Answer (score 2):

It is thread safe (since it can't be modified).  It passes the same copy around.

However, the wrapped List (`tagList`) is still NOT thread safe.  You must not modify the wrapped List while it's being shared.  The only reason the list returned by `unmodifiableList()` is safe is because modifications are not allowed through it to the wrapped List.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that the list is unmodifialble; hence it will be thread safe.

When you pass an object you actually pass the reference to the object (and not the actual object). As there is a single copy and its not getting modified so it will remain thread safe.

**Just one caution**; never access **tagList** directly. Access it always through wrapped unmodifiable collection named as **tList**. This can be achieved if you encapsulate it properly.